# SystemJS Block Comments formatting can cause errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, systemjs

If anyone encounters the  following error using SystemJS + TypeScript and ES5, please note the problem is with the block comments.  Changing the format or removing comments in the .js files will fix the problem.

```
Uncaught Error: Module http://localhost:4400/scripts/xxxxxxx.js interpreted as global module format, but called System.register.
system.src.js (2782,19)
```

The following block comments in my .ts file cause errors.

```
// import {enableDebugTools} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
/**
 * Used to demonstrate external module is loading and function is called.
 */
```

However, if I change the comments to use the following comment structure, I don't get an error:

```
 // import {enableDebugTools} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
 // Used to demonstrate external module is loading and function is called.
```

*Module format detection in SystemJS is not designed to be 100% accurate, it is designed to cater to the majority use case. -- Guy Bedford*

Output JavaScript from TypeScript has the comment in it.  Definitely not a problem with TypeScript compiler.
[image]
[image]

Error Message from VS2015
[image]

Comment: what is the outputed javascript for that comment?

Comment: Its a good idea to post the reply for an issue you already know the answer, its encouraged by SO. but could please you write it as a question, and then answer yourself? In 24h you will be able to mark your answer as approved.

Comment: @toskv added screen shots of JavaScript.  Here's the repo with the code.  [https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta](https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta) .  Note, it's for VS2015